# Script Type(s) for Updating All Item Records in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm still new to NetSuite, so I appreciate any help you all can provide. I've created a script to update a couple custom fields on item records. Currently, it is a Client script, and while I do want it to execute when a user updates a record, I'd also like it to execute after a server update as well. In addition, I'd like to apply this to all current item records to provide a baseline for future changes.

Have I made this overly complicated? What script type should I be using? Can I get this done with one script, or do I need multiples? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one User Event script that would run whenever a record is updated. you can deploy the script to run on items. In the user event you can check for context (e.g.: user interface, particular script type, maxss update etc.) if you do not want to run it in all context

Comment: Interesting, I tried making a User Event script, but it didn't run when we employed the server update. What am I missing?

Comment: did you set the deployment mode to released and make sure it is deployed correctly?

Comment: Is that defined in the script record? I added my function to the "After Submit Function" field on the Scripts subtab, and then I deployed the script to "Inventory Part". Oh! My "Status" is "Testing", should I change that to "Released"? To be honest, I don't even know what that is.

Comment: yes, testing is for current user i.e. script owner only

Comment: Okay, that is really good to know. I will make that change and let you know what happens. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Bam, this worked! Thanks, prasun! This is totally a newb mistake, but it definitely produced the result I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also write a Mass Update script that you can use to update all existing records.

Comment: @egrubaugh360 but, you can't write mass update that runs automatically when a record is updated

Comment: @prasun - Right, that's the job of the User Event. The Mass Update would be to get all existing records caught up, if necessary.